# Append to a nested list with unknown dimensions

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, nested, nested-lists

I want to take the dimensions of the nested list as desired from the user.
Then append strings given by the user to the corresponding elements.
Find the string of maximum Length in the nested list to properly left justify text.
Then left justify the string to print the strings in the tabular form.
The program should go about this

```
Enter the number of main items in the list: 3
Enter the number of sub items that each list will contain: 4
(1,1):apples
(1,2):oranges
(1,3):cherries
(1,4):banana
(2,1):Alice
(2,2):Bob
(2,3):Carol
(2,4):David
(3,1):dogs
(3,2):cats
(3,3):moose
(3,4):goose
Following list must be created in the program
listOfList= [ ['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
              ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
              ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
output given by a print table function should be like this:
'''
apples   Alice  dogs
oranges  Bob    cats
cherries Carol  moose
banana   David  goose
```

Here is my actual code

```
#Organising Lists of Lists in tablular Form
x=int(input("Enter the number of main items in the list: "))
y=int(input("Enter the number of sub items that each list will contain: "))
listOfList=[[]]
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        listOfList[i][j]=input('('+str(i+1)+','+str(j+1)+'):')
def printTable(nestedList):
    maxLen=0
    #this loop finds the max Length of any string in the nestedList
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            if len(nestedList[i][j])>maxLen:
                maxLen=len(nestedList[i][j])
    #Loop to display table
    for j in range(y):
        for i in range(x):
            print(nestedList[i][j].ljust(maxLen),sep=' ', end='')
        print()
printTable(listOfList)
```

Error occured:

```
Enter the number of main items in the list: 3
Enter the number of sub items that each list will contain: 4
(1,1):apples
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyscripts\printTable.py", line 7, in <module>
    listOfList[i][j]=input('('+str(i+1)+','+str(j+1)+'):')
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Initialize list and use it. You are trying to add index in empty list. We cant assign index in empty list. Try with initialize you will get answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have pointed out the key issue that you haven't pre-allocated space in the list and that attempting to assign to non-existent indices will cause the error you're getting, however:

You can avoid pre-initialising the list by building it in a list comp from the inputs, eg:

```
x = int(input('X: '))
y = int(input('Y: '))

lol = [
    [input('({},{}): '.format(b, a)) for a in range(1,  y + 1)]
    for b in range(1, x + 1)
]
```

Then you can calculate your maximum word length without explicitly looping and keeping track of the maximum value by using:

```
max_length = max(len(word) for lst in lol for word in lst)
```

Then, instead of looping over the reverse indices, you can use `zip` to transpose rows/columns and print each line by joining the words padding to the maximum length, eg:

```
for line in zip(*lol):
    print(' '.join(word.ljust(max_length) for word in line))
```

This gives you:

```
apples   Alice    dogs    
oranges  Bob      cats    
cherries Carol    moose   
banana   David    goose
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your list first:

```
listOfList = [[0 for w in range(y)] for h in range(x)]
```

Output:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> listOfList = [[0 for w in range(y)] for h in range(x)]
>>> listOfList
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You see your listOfList has problem

```
>>>len(listOfList)
1
```

BUT

```
>>>len(listOfList[0])
0
```

which means you inner list is empty, so you can't access listOfList[0][0]

```
 >>>listOfList[0][0]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 IndexError: list index out of range
```